# How to show horizontal line instead of a dot for a single value data in highcharts

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

everyone, I am using highcharts to show graphs. Currently, for a single value, it is showing a dot in a graph as shown in a screenshot. Instead of a dot, I want a horizontal line parallel to the x-axis. Can anyone help me to solve this? Thank you.

[image]

```
Ref: https://jsfiddle.net/5syn3ko1/
```

Note: please copy and paste the URL in the browser for code sandbox. It is showing an error when I paste the link.

Comment: Are you trying to get a horizontal across the whole chart, or do you want to replace the dot with a small horizontal line at that point?

Comment: I want a horizontal line across the whole chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding a series with single values, use plot lines:

```
    xAxis: {
        plotLines: [{
            value: 2010,
            color: 'blue'
        }],
        ...
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3654z2yw/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotLines